# Resizing UI elements Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, resize

How can I automatically resize the elements in my UI (built in Interface Builder) when the user resizes the window? Similar to what happens when you resize a Safari window, the WebView automatically resizes.

Comment: Are you asking how to have subviews resize along with their superview in Interface Builder, or in the final running app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the autoresizing mask on your view.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-autoresizingMask

This mask tells the view how to resize itself when needed.  You specify whether or not the borders should remain where they are relative to its parent, and whether the width and height are stretchable if needed.